# Secured RSocket throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Neither SslContextBuilder nor SslContext is specified

Tags: ssl, netty, reactor-netty, rsocket

I am trying to start a secured RSocket using a certificate and its private key but I can't figure out why it throws an exception in the `secure{...}` statement: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Neither SslContextBuilder nor SslContext is specified`

```
    RSocketFactory.receive()
        .frameDecoder(PayloadDecoder.DEFAULT)
        .acceptor { setup, sendingSocket ->
            Mono.just(
                object : AbstractRSocket() {
                    override fun requestStream(payload: Payload): Flux<Payload> {
                        val randomNumberGenerator = Random(1234)
                        val numbers = payload.dataUtf8.toInt()
                        println("Generating $numbers random numbers")
                        return IntRange(1, numbers)
                            .map { DefaultPayload.create(randomNumberGenerator.nextUInt().toString().toByteArray()) }
                            .toList().toFlux()
                    }
                })
        }
        .transport(
            TcpServerTransport.create(TcpServer.create().port(7878).secure {
                SslContextBuilder.forServer(
                    File(RequestStreamRSocket::class.java.getResource("certificate.pem").toURI()),
                    File(RequestStreamRSocket::class.java.getResource("key.pem").toURI())
                )
            })
        )
        .start()
        .block()
        ?.onClose()
```

Full log:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:60628,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:/Users/jose/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.2/groovyHotSwap/gragent.jar -javaagent:/Users/jose/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2019.2/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_201.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/jose/git/codependent/github/rsocket-simple-client/build/classes/java/main:/Users/jose/git/codependent/github/rsocket-simple-client/out/production/resources:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.50/bf65725d4ae2cf00010d84e945fcbc201f590e11/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.50.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.rsocket/rsocket-transport-netty/1.0.0-RC5/7d0093068e332fcbfa3e9f5de971174a795a9122/rsocket-transport-netty-1.0.0-RC5.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.rsocket/rsocket-core/1.0.0-RC5/fbe165e1e57c5748a40af66832206c4616aa6290/rsocket-core-1.0.0-RC5.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.50/50ad05ea1c2595fb31b800e76db464d08d599af3/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.50.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.50/b529d1738c7e98bbfa36a4134039528f2ce78ebf/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.50.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.projectreactor.netty/reactor-netty/0.9.0.RELEASE/f0a0ae4e38ad8b36596ffe4bf82519cf8fc4adfb/reactor-netty-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-http2/4.1.39.Final/6e4660fb8b1054e34e09aa95a10115edf0d74f37/netty-codec-http2-4.1.39.Final.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-handler-proxy/4.1.39.Final/8a5c8a0b4ceb75531d04a14e0e65839ee07f2378/netty-handler-proxy-4.1.39.Final.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.39.Final/732d06961162e27fa3ae5989541c4460853745d3/netty-codec-http-4.1.39.Final.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-handler/4.1.39.Final/4a63b56de071c1b10a56b5d90095e4201ea4098f/netty-handler-4.1.39.Final.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.39.Final/ab86de9bb5fccbfb60a9c0036a3516ad9b8befbb/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.39.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-socks/4.1.39.Final/adc3df7362874b53c11e56f79c53ebea97d29aa7/netty-codec-socks-4.1.39.Final.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec/4.1.39.Final/38b9d79e31f6b00bd680f88c0289a2522d30d05b/netty-codec-4.1.39.Final.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.39.Final/e5d94d2f6847919afbbfdb08a7a9e1f9ae19b101/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport/4.1.39.Final/25374210da8a561689c4280e9d5661ff5dee30b7/netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-buffer/4.1.39.Final/3518c7c7d0097460eeeaba32fb0c241b9cbe628a/netty-buffer-4.1.39.Final.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.projectreactor/reactor-core/3.3.0.RELEASE/4824f980e5696e95289d5fb0de62e3d34508b358/reactor-core-3.3.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/da76ca59f6a57ee3102f8f9bd9cee742973efa8a/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.50/3d9cd3e1bc7b92e95f43d45be3bfbcf38e36ab87/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.50.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-resolver/4.1.39.Final/2ca0a547341ba72dacf60121302357e7ea110b96/netty-resolver-4.1.39.Final.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-common/4.1.39.Final/9c8c6d0dd43ee26ec8052a42d3ee1113dc6c08ed/netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.3/d9fb7a7926ffa635b3dcaa5049fb2bfa25b3e7d0/reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar:/Users/jose/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.projectreactor.addons/reactor-pool/0.1.0.RELEASE/3aa0e33a1647a85e94bea47d7efb57c46977c71a/reactor-pool-0.1.0.RELEASE.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" RequestStreamRSocketKt
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60628', transport: 'socket'
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Neither SslContextBuilder nor SslContext is specified
    at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider.<init>(SslProvider.java:313)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.SslProvider$Build.build(SslProvider.java:551)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServerSecure.secure(TcpServerSecure.java:36)
    at reactor.netty.tcp.TcpServer.secure(TcpServer.java:458)
    at RequestStreamRSocketKt.main(RequestStreamRSocket.kt:45)
    at RequestStreamRSocketKt.main(RequestStreamRSocket.kt)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:60628', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I wasn't setting the `SslContext` into the `SslProvider.SslContextSpec`:

```
.transport(
    TcpServerTransport.create(TcpServer.create().port(7878).secure {
        it.sslContext(
            SslContextBuilder.forServer(
                File(RequestStreamRSocket::class.java.getResource("certificate.pem").toURI())
                File(RequestStreamRSocket::class.java.getResource("key.pem").toURI())
            )
        )
    })
)
```